# NullPointerException openOrCreateDatabase Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i m gettin a NullPointerException in my EhActivity class while opening a database

```
 public class EHActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String>ques= new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String>ans=new ArrayList<String>();
 SQLiteDatabase db2;

  public ArrayList<String> getQues()
  {
   db2=openOrCreateDatabase("interview.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   db2.execSQL("create table eh (qid int primary key,ques varchar,ans char)");
       db2.execSQL("insert into subject values(1,'What is an exception?','A1 '))");
   db2.execSQL("insert into subject values(2,'What is error?','A2 '))");
       Cursor c=db2.rawQuery("select * from eh",null);
   while(c.moveToNext())
   {
    ques.add(c.getString(1));
   }
   return ques;
  }
 }
```

log cat view is:

> 03-21 14:06:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(955): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-21 14:06:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
>   03-21 14:06:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at interview.android.EHActivity.getQues(EHActivity.java:19)

Comment: I suspect you are calling `getQues()` before `onCreate()` was called (e.g. from a constructor of `EHActivity`) - Your activity context is not initialized then

Comment: @zapl i have tried using onCreate() function but same error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

try not sending null..
openOrCreateDatabase has another method for this..

```
db2=openOrCreateDatabase("interview.db", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
openDatabase("interview.db", MODE_PRIVATE, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)
```

Comment: no the function is not allowed for two parameters 3rd parameter factory must be pass and hence the project will not run..

Comment: ok try this- openDatabase("interview.db", MODE_PRIVATE, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY).

Comment: the value of factory CREATE_IF_NECESSARY is not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Database_creat {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "interview.db";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_TODO_LIST = "todo_list";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public ArrayList<ModelToDO> list;


    private DataBaseHelper mDbhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    Context mContext;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CATEGORY = "create table category(id integer primary key autoincrement , "
            + "category text not null);";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TODO_LIST = "create table todo_list(id integer primary key autoincrement , "
            + "title text not null,description text not null,category text not null, due_date Date not null,alarm_time text ,alarm_set text,priority text,parform Boolean);";

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CATEGORY);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TODO_LIST);
        }

        //Delete All todo_list Table info
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS submit");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Database_creat(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public Database_creat Open() throws SQLException {
        mDbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
        mDb = mDbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        mDbhelper.close();
    }

    //Add new Category name
    public long insertinfo(String cate) {
        ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
        con.put("category", cate);
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CATEGORY, null, con);
    }


}
```

this one create database in used query

Answer (score 0):

HI Shubh Try The Following Code..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


db2=openOrCreateDatabase("sdcard/yourappfolder/interview.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: db2.execSQL("insert into subject values(1,'What is an exception?','A1 '))");

Here you are closing 3 bracket .while u have opened only two.
delete one bracket that is second from last.